# Координаты через GoogleApiClient. GPS запускается, а потом останавливается

Tags: java, android, gps, google-api

Задавал вопрос на англоязычном SO - результата нету. Попробую спросить здесь.

Мне в приложении нужны текущие координаты устройства. Для их получения  использую GoogleApiClient:

```
public class MapInterface implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    public MapInterface() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Application.AppContext)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, createLocationRequest(), this);
        mlastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lastLocation = location;
    }

    protected LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        return locationRequest;
    }
}
```

Когда создается экземпляр класса MapInterface метод `onConnected()` вполне нормально вызывается и вызов `requestLocationUpdates()` успешен (при первом вызове андроид 5 запрашивает у пользователя разрешение на получение координат).

После этого на статус-баре появляется иконка с GPS антенной (как на картинке ниже) и строка с данными GPS в области уведомлений, но сразу после этого она исчезает. Иногда иконка GPS отображается чуть дольше и GPS успевает включиться и отобразить в области уведомления количество спутников. Если класс запускать несколько раз, то GPS перед отключением может схватить привязку и даже координаты в области уведомлений показать.

Самое интересное, что интерфейс `onLocationChanged()` вызывается с заданной периодичностью, но полученные данные похоже совсем не точные, хотя приоритет указан  PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY. GPS после старта не работает и не используется - нет значка на статусбаре, нет строки в области уведомления (хотя при запуске 2gis например GPS вполне нормально используется и работает).

Пробовал использовать `Context.LOCATION_SERVICE` - результат такой же. Необходимые разрешения в манифесте имеются. Пробовал перемещаться с телефоном и запускать определение координат в других местах - не помогло.

Скриншот с иконкой GPS:
[image: С иконкой GPS]

Тот же статус-бар спустя несколько секунд:
[image: Без иконки GPS]

Это вообще нормальное поведение или я где-то что-то упустил ?

Comment: Локацию потом забираете? Посмотрите вот тут http://stackoverflow.com/a/33023788/5892568 описывается поведение если нет клиента который забирает данные, не оно?

Comment: Локация приходит по интерфейсу LocationListener и автоматом забирается. Я тут экспериментировал и выяснил, что GPS можно заставить работать нормально если выставить некоторую комбинацию из  setInterval(ххх) и setFastestInterval(ххх), но понять от чего зависит это соотношение не могу. Соотношение 2000 и 15000 работает. 6500/20000 не работает... 6500/30000 работает

Comment: Время может зависеть от многих факторов -  чипсета, доступности a-GPS, вы кстати тестируете на открытом пространстве (сужу по скриншоту с USB) - минимум на окне, можно проверить по GPS статус утилите видимость спутников и т.д.

Comment: В общем проблему то решил (поставил 4000/20000) и гпс стартует и работает без отключения и даже координаты точные дает каждые 20 секунд если к окну поднести, но логику работы понять не могу никак. 5000/20000 уже гаснет. При 5000/30000 работает.

Comment: и 4000/20000 это как-то маловато... Батарейку видимо жрать будет...